# check data should be in two column format with comma | unix |

Tags: linux, shell

I have a data in file

```
File : Student.txt 
AB,A1
BC,A2
CD,A3
  ,A4   --> not in proper format position value is missing  
MM,A5
SD      --> not in proper format position value is missing

How to write code so that the Position 0 : AB , Position 0 : A1  should be with comma (,)
```

**Both the position values should be present if one of them is not present then it should display message like file is not in proper format**

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question? Have you tried something and are you stuck? If you expect someone to do the work for you, it's a custom in our culture to pay for work of others. To solve your problem, learn regexes, I recommend https://regexcrossword.com/ . Then use `awk` or `sed` to match the line (or match the wrongly formatted data) and implement your check.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a text file line by line to check whether it is comma-delimited with two values separated by a comma? If so, do you want it to check whether both values are a particular length as well (i.e. two character strings like your example)?

Comment: @Carley  is am using while loop when i process first record which is AB,A1 -> i want to add a check like the their as to be two parameter first parameter AB and Second A1 if either of them is missing then exit the loop with message the file is not in proper format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
msg="not in proper format position value is missing"
while read -r line; do
    col1="${line%,*}"
    col2="${line#*,}"
    [[ -z $col1 || -z $col2 || $line != *","* ]] && echo "'$line' $msg"
done < Student.txt
```

Explanation:

```
-z $col1        check if first column has no value
-z $col2        check if second column has no value
$line != *","*  check if line contains no comma
```